# Pass Perameter from textbox to RDLC report

Tags: c#, winforms, c#-4.0, rdlc

I want to display some values from textboxes on RDLC report.
 following is the code which throw an error 'An error occurred during local report processing.'
 i also upload my  form

```
ReportParameter param_DateFrom = new ReportParameter("DateTimePickerFrom", DatemePickerFrom.Value.Date.ToShortDateString(), false);
ReportParameter param_DateTo = new ReportParameter("DateTimePickerTo", DateTimePickerTo.Value.Date.ToShortDateString(), false);
ReportParameter paramAccountNo = new ReportParameter("AccountNo", textBoxAccountNo.Text, false);
ReportParameter paramNamefname = new ReportParameter("NameFname", textBoxName.Text, false);
ReportParameter paramAddress = new ReportParameter("Address", textBoxAddress.Text, false);
ReportParameter paramAccountType = new ReportParameter("AccounType", txtAccountType.Text, false);
ReportParameter paramOpeningBalance = new ReportParameter("OpeningBalance", textBoxOpeningBalance.Text, false);
//ReportParameter paramBankName = new ReportParameter("BankName",comboBoxBanks.SelectedText,false);

this.reportViewer1.LocalReport.SetParameters(new ReportParameter[] { param_DateFrom, param_DateTo, paramAccountNo, paramNamefname, paramAddress, paramAccountType, paramOpeningBalance});
this.reportViewer1.LocalReport.Refresh();

this.ReportBetweenDatesTableAdapter.Fill(this.DataSet1.ReportBetweenDates, Convert.ToInt32(comboBoxBanks.SelectedValue), DateTimePickerFrom.Value, DateTimePickerTo.Value);
this.reportViewer1.RefreshReport();
```

[image]

Comment: Probably you have error in assigning values, for example passing empty or null value to a parameter that is not allowed to be null or empty or a type mismatch, put your code in a `try{}catch(Exception ex){}` block and see `ex.InnerException.Message` it will show you to the main error.

Comment: i think this is the problem Dear @Reza

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In such cases you should put your code in a try/catch block and look at `Exception` and `InnerExcception`.

Probably you have error in assigning values, for example passing empty or null value to a parameter that is not allowed to be null or empty or a type mismatch.

To figure out the error, put your code in a `try{}catch(Exception ex){}` block and see `ex.InnerException.Message` it will show you to the main error.

Then to fix the problem, go to your report designer and make the parameter accept null and empty values or provide a suitable value for that parameter.

**For example:**

```
try
{
    ReportParameter param_DateFrom = new ReportParameter("DateTimePickerFrom", DateTimePickerFrom.Value.Date.ToShortDateString(), false);
    ReportParameter param_DateTo = new ReportParameter("DateTimePickerTo", DateTimePickerTo.Value.Date.ToShortDateString(), false);
    ReportParameter paramAccountNo = new ReportParameter("AccountNo", textBoxAccountNo.Text, false);
    ReportParameter paramNamefname = new ReportParameter("NameFname", textBoxName.Text, false);
    ReportParameter paramAddress = new ReportParameter("Address", textBoxAddress.Text, false);

    ReportParameter paramAccountType = new ReportParameter("AccounType", txtAccountType.Text, false);
    ReportParameter paramOpeningBalance = new ReportParameter("OpeningBalance", textBoxOpeningBalance.Text, false);
    //ReportParameter paramBankName = new ReportParameter("BankName",comboBoxBanks.SelectedText,false);

    this.reportViewer1.LocalReport.SetParameters(new ReportParameter[] { param_DateFrom, param_DateTo, paramAccountNo, paramNamefname, paramAddress, paramAccountType, paramOpeningBalance });
    this.reportViewer1.LocalReport.Refresh();
    this.ReportBetweenDatesTableAdapter.Fill(this.DataSet1.ReportBetweenDates, Convert.ToInt32(comboBoxBanks.SelectedValue), DateTimePickerFrom.Value, DateTimePickerTo.Value);
    this.reportViewer1.RefreshReport();
}
catch (Exception ex)
{
    var message = ex.Message;
    if (ex.InnerException != null)
        message += "\n" + ex.InnerException.Message;
    MessageBox.Show(message );
}
```

Comment: Weldone Reza Aghaei , you are great. it solve my problem :)