# How get winForm textbox value to textbox in report1.rdlc file in C# windows form application

Tags: c#, winforms, textbox, rdlc, report-viewer2010

I created a project in C# windows form application in VS2010 and .net framework version 4.0

My project main form contains Print Form. And Print Form has reportviewer1 control. For that I created a report1.rdlc file.

Main form contains textboxes like tb_SerialNo, tb_TypeNo, tb_Date, tb_TestEngineer etc.I need that textboxes value in my report1.rdlc file textbox.

Please help me to solve this issue. thanks in Advance.

Comment: Create a parameter in report and in the report, show the parameter value in the report text box. Then in the application, [pass parameter](https://stackoverflow.com/a/33399682/3110834) value to the report.

Comment: Thanks, I created parameters and I got the textbox value in rdlc file and also in report viewer.